# Debug Assertion Failed Expression: _format_parser.error_code() == 0

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, n;
    float p;

    printf("Please enter article characteristics.\n");
    printf("Article Number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    printf("Number of pieces: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("Price per piece: ");
    scanf_s("%.1f", &p);

    printf("\n\tArticle Number\tQuantity\tPrice Per Piece\n");
    printf("\t     %d\t\t%d\t     %.1f Dollar", a, n, p);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I'm able to input the first part but once I input the second I get the error. Even when I remove the second part I get the error when I put my first input.

Answer (score 1):

The user input may differ from person to person so it's better to use scanf("%f", &p) rather than using scanf("%.1f", &p) but when displaying the values or when performing other operations, you can make changes to one(.1f) or two(.2f) decimal places according to your need. Here is the correct code below:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a, n;
    float p;
    printf("Please enter article characteristics.\n");
    printf("Article Number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Number of pieces: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Price per piece: ");
    scanf("%f", &p);
  
    printf("\n\tArticle Number\tQuantity\tPrice Per Piece\n");
    printf("\t     %d\t\t%d\t     %.1f Dollar", a, n, p);
    return 0;
}
```

You can view a sample output below [image: Click here to view the sample output]